# youtube-dl not working signature algorithm

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am getting this error when I am trying to download a video from youtube via `youtube-dl`:

```
WARNING: Warning: Falling back to static signature algorithm
ERROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Is this happening for one video in particular or is it all videos?

Answer (score 0):

The copy of `youtube-dl` in the Ubuntu Repositories is often quite old and Youtube frequently changes the way it serves files rendering older versions of `youtube-dl` ineffective. Use the following to get a modern copy:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y youtube-dl
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
hash -r
```

You should find that your error will no longer appear. Routinely update your installation (every week or so) by running:

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

In fact it will be mandatory for you to update / upgrade in this way as `youtube-dl` will not be a standard Ubuntu Repository package.

**Reference:**

- [How do I update youtube-dl?](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl)